# How are Infinite sets compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

A set is compact iff every open cover of the set has a finite subcover. Also, every set can be expressed as a union of singleton sets(which are open). So my question is how can a set containing infinite elements be compact ($[1,2]$ for an instance) considering the open cover consisting of singleton sets??

Comment: If singletons are open, $[1,2]$ is not compact.

Comment: This is a category error. Sets cannot be compact, **topological spaces** may be.

Comment: Yeah, in the usual topology, singletons are definitely not open.  The topology matters.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown A subset of a topological space can be compact---it is not wrong to ask if a set is compact.  It is wrong to do so without specifying a topology, but the basic question is reasonable.

Comment: Sets can be compact *in a given topology*. $[0, 1]$ is compact in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but is clearly not in the discrete topology (the one where singletons are open).

Comment: Everyone is correct:  a subset of a space is compact if and only if it is itself compact in its own subspace topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the open cover consisting of singleton sets

An *open cover* isn't just any old collection of sets which cover the given space - it's a collection of *open sets* which cover the given space. So when you say "the open cover consisting of singleton sets," you're assuming **every singleton set is open**.

This isn't true in general - e.g. in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, singletons are closed but not open. (In fact, "every singleton is open" is a very strong property - if $(X,\tau)$ is a space where every singleton is open, then *every* subset of $X$ is open in the sense of $\tau$.)

---

At this point it's worth being careful about what a topological space is, exactly. A topological space is a pair $(X,\tau)$ where

- $X$ is some set (like $\mathbb{R}$), and
- $\tau$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ (the "open sets") with a few properties ($\tau$ is closed under finite intersections, arbitrary unions, and we need $X,\emptyset\in\tau$).

Often when $\tau$ is obvious from context, we just talk about $X$ on its own - e.g. when we say "$(0, 1)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$" - but this is technically wrong! Instead, we should say something like "$(0,1)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ *with the Euclidean topology*."